# onchange function is triggered twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to use the values from a JQuery multi datepicker for a different purpose, but for some reason when I did a test on the values I got, I kept getting the same thing twice. Am I missing something?

My Code :

```js
$('.date').datepicker({
  multidate: true,
  format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
});

function printDates() {
  var dates = document.getElementById("date_input").value;
  console.log(dates);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'></script>


<input type="text" name="dates" class="form-control date" id="date_input" placeholder="Pick the dates " onchange="printDates()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use changeDate insstead of onchange as below

```js
$('.date').datepicker({
  multidate: true,
  format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
})
.on('changeDate', function(e) {
       printDates(); // `e` here contains the extra attributes
    });
;

function printDates() {
  var dates = document.getElementById("date_input").value;
  console.log(dates);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'></script>


<input type="text" name="dates" class="form-control date" id="date_input" placeholder="Pick the dates " >
```

Answer (score 1):

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html

Use the change event provided in bootstrap datepicker.